# Why Java EE Timers are not clustering?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.2

I am working with Java EE EJB timers and Wildfly 8.2.1 server with oracle database.When run a scheduler in my application at cluster environment not working fine,even though selected Transaction Isolation: TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE in Wildfly.I am deploying in two nodes it accessing from two node but I need one node only.

In EJB:

```
@Singleton 
public class TimerSessionBean implements TimerSessionBeanRemote {
@Timeout
    @Schedule(
            hour="11",minute="0",second="00,30"
            )
    public void createTimer(){
        System.out.println("timeoutHandler : "+new Date());
DAO.getInboxDaoImpl().updateStatus();

    }
```

In DaoImpl:

```
@Override
    public Boolean updateStatus(String chngCustStus){
        int resVal = 0;

            String sql = "INSERT INTO bonus SELECT ename, job, sal, comm FROM emp
   WHERE comm > sal * 0.25";

        } 
    }
```

where In Wildfly server: selected as

```
 Transaction Isolation:  TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Clustered EJB timers are available in WildFly 9 and newer.

Documentation can be found at:

1. [WildFly 9 | EJB3 Clustered Database Timers](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/EJB3+Clustered+Database+Timers)
2. [WildFly 10 | EJB3 Clustered Database Timers](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB3+Clustered+Database+Timers)

Most Java EE implementations support this one way or another, but @38leinad is indeed correct that this behaviour is not specified anywhere.

Early versions of JBossAS 7 -> WildFly 8.x missed out because it was a completely new implementation of the specification and the focus was on Java EE 6 and then Java EE 7 compliance.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed the expected behaviour.

There is no notion of a cluster in the Java EE spec. So, there is no portable solution. On JBoss i haved in the past used the Quartz timer.
Specifically for Wildfly 8, have a check if [this post](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/creating-clustered-ejb-3-timers) answers you question.